# ScrollViewer does not scroll Image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have an image that is bigger than it's window container and it is placed in a ScrollViewer, however, the image does not scroll at all. I've tried putting the image in a container with no luck. What settings am I missing here? (I copied the code straight from MS, but they have it wrong)

Here's the code:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:h="http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com" x:Class="TileLayout"
Title="TileLayout" Height="1000" Width="845" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSourceFilePath" Width="500" Margin="10" Height="22" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Text="E:\projects\Test3D\SavedSnapshots\snapshot.png"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnPickFile" Width="100" Margin="0,10,10,10" Content="Pick File" ></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <Image x:Name="imgFinal" Source="SteelMotion_chevron2.png"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I just discovered what many others did is that a ScrollViewer does not work inside of a StackPanel. Is this really true? Is it just that no one has figured out how to do it?

Comment: Ya it's true, unless you hard set the height, it's by design. Just use a `Grid` instead.

Comment: I tried the height setting - it had no effect.
        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

No room to post my final code that works with the grid. But I switched to Grid and scrolling works now.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:h="http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com" x:Class="TileLayout"
Title="TileLayout" Height="1000" Width="845" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSourceFilePath" Width="500" Margin="10" Height="22" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Text=""/>
        <Button x:Name="btnPickFile" Width="100" Margin="0,10,10,10" Content="Pick File" ></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Image x:Name="imgFinal" Source="SteelMotion_chevron2.png" Width="768" Height="1408"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of the ScrollViewer.
In this case ScrollViewer and Image are same size, so the scroll bar does not show.